# Format Excel export file with C#

Tags: c#, excel

I'm trying to format my `C#` file in order to Export Data to `Excel file`.
I would like to center each column and data filled inside.
I use : **OfficeOpenXml.Style**
I don't know why, but some data into columns don't respect the centered directive.

I have this code :

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Create excel sheet from a template
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="almostPreparedData"></param>
    protected override void AlmostPreparedData(IData almostPreparedData)
    {
        var ListeDesGroupesNotationsItemVM = ObjectData.GetObjectValue<ListeDesGroupesDeNotationPsVm>(almostPreparedData);

        using (var package = new ExcelPackage(ExecEnv.Implementation.GetStreamForLocalFile(
            $"App_GlobalResources\\ExcelTemplate\\{LocalizationContextMinimal.CurrentUICulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName}\\{EXCEL_TEMPLATE}"))
        )
        {
            var worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[1];

            // Insert number of needed lines
            if (ListeDesGroupesNotationsItemVM.Resultat.Count > 2)
            {
                worksheet.InsertRow(6, ListeDesGroupesNotationsItemVM.Resultat.Count - 2, 5);
            }
            else if (ListeDesGroupesNotationsItemVM.Resultat.Count < 2)
            {
                // une ligne est présente en plus dans le template pour faire office de modèle
                worksheet.DeleteRow(5, 1);
            }

            var ligne = 4;
            for (int j = 1; j < 14; j++)
            {
                foreach (var resultat in ListeDesGroupesNotationsItemVM.Resultat)
                {
                
                    worksheet.Cells[ligne, j].Style.HorizontalAlignment = ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Center;
                    worksheet.Cells[ligne, 1].Value = resultat.Nom;
                    worksheet.Cells[ligne, 2].Value = resultat.IdCMCIC;
                    worksheet.Cells[ligne, 3].Value = resultat.NomGac;
                    worksheet.Cells[ligne, 4].Value = resultat.Refbilancielle;
                    worksheet.Cells[ligne, 5].Value = resultat.Cotation;
                    worksheet.Cells[ligne, 6].Value = resultat.Secteur;
                    worksheet.Cells[ligne, 7].Value = resultat.CodeAlgo != null ? resultat.CodeAlgo.ExchangeValue.ToString() : string.Empty;
                    worksheet.Cells[ligne, 8].Value = resultat.CodeSegment != null ? resultat.CodeSegment.ExchangeValue.ToString() : string.Empty;
                    worksheet.Cells[ligne, 9].Value = resultat.DateDerniereCotation;
                    worksheet.Cells[ligne, 10].Value = resultat.StatutsEtapeWorkflow?.ToString() ?? string.Empty;
                    worksheet.Cells[ligne, 11].Value = resultat.Statut ? "Actif" : "Inactif";
                    worksheet.Cells[ligne, 12].Value = resultat.PolePresentateur;
                    worksheet.Cells[ligne, 13].Value = resultat.Pays;
                    ligne++;
                }

            }

            var streamData = DataToolkit.SetStream(package.GetAsByteArray(), null, null);
            Document = new Document(streamData)
            {
                Filename = EXCEL_FILENAME
                    .Replace("{titre}", I18N.Translate("ListeDesGroupesNotation"))
                    .Replace("{date}", DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()),
                OpenWith = DocumentViewer.ExternalDocumentViewer,
                ContentType = ContentTypes.Xlsx
            };
        }
    }
```

But when I try to generate my Excel file, I can see some solumns with data uncentered inside. I don't know if my code : `worksheet.Cells[ligne, j].Style.HorizontalAlignment = ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Center;` doesn't work or if the issue comes from another thing ?

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Try using:

`xlCenter` instead of just `.center`

Comment: @KGB91 I have to import which library ? Because `xlCenter` is not proposed by VisualStudio in my code.

Comment: Try using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`

Comment: I have to use OfficeOpenXml.Style, I don't have possibility to use another library :/

Comment: Okay, I think that should be put into the question.